# RegEx : Insert space in the string after a matched pattern

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

In Java I want to insert a space after a string but only if the string contains "MAVERICK". I think using replaceAll() method which uses regular expressions as a parameter will do it, but i am not really getting it.

Here is what i have

```
String s = "MAVERICKA";
//the last character can be from the following set [A,Z,T,SE,EX]
```

So, i want the function to return me the string "MAVERICK A" or "MAVERICK EX".
Ex.

- MAVERICKA -> MAVERICK A
- MAVERICKEX -> MAVERICK EX

Also, if the string is already in the correct format it should not insert a space. i.e

- MAVERICK A -> MAVERICK A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like

```
s = s.replaceAll("MAVERICK(A|Z|T|SE|EX)", "MAVERICK $1");
```

Comment: can this be used with Matcher. like matcher.replaceAll("");it seems matcher only takes one param

Comment: Yes, `replaceAll` from String is using `replaceAll` from `Matcher`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution without knowing the trailing letters would be:

```
String spaced_out = s.replaceAll("(MAVERICK)(?!\s|$)", "$1 ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this:

```
String r = s.replaceAll("(MAVERICK)([AZT]|SE|EX)", "$1 $2");
```